# Creating nested dictionary from indented text input

Tags: python

I have a text input which is in this format-

```
var="""
interface A
  member-1
  member-2
    submember-1
    submember-2
interface B
  member-1
interface C

"""
```

I will have to convert this into a python nested dictionary form like the following. And also any element which doesnt have a sub member is to be assigned value -1.

```
result=
{
'interface A':{'member-1': -1 ,'member-2':{'submember-1': -1,'submember-2': -1}}
'interface B' :{'member-1': -1},
'interface C': -1
}
```

I am trying to do it in a recursive way, but dont seem to get my logic right. What is the best/pythonic way to do this.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: `I am trying to do it in a recursive way` <- show us how, so we can show you how to fix it

Answer (score 1):

its a bit ugly but if u dont have too many indentation level this code can be useful

```
_dict = {}
for line in var.split('\n'):
    if line.strip():
        print line
        leading_spaces = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
        if leading_spaces == 0:
            interface = line.strip()
            _dict[interface] = -1
        elif leading_spaces == 2:
            member = line.strip()
            if _dict[interface] == -1:
                _dict[interface] = {member:-1}
            else:
                _dict[interface].update({member:-1})
        elif leading_spaces == 4:
            print _dict
            submember = line.strip()
            if _dict[interface][member] == -1:
                _dict[interface][member] = {submember:-1}
            else:
                _dict[interface][member].update({submember:-1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a fine strategy for something like this, though somewhat complicated by the fact that a) you have to keep track of which line in the input string you are currently processing, and b)you have to be peeking ahead and looking at the indentation levels of future lines to figure out when a particular recursive call should return.

One solution is to use a generator to get successive lines, and a recursive function that takes the current line and the line-generator, and returns both the dictionary and the "next line".

```
from collections import namedtuple
LineData = namedtuple('LineData', 'indent text')

def yield_linedata(text):
    yield LineData(indent=-1, text='')
    for line in text.split('\n'):
        if line.strip() != '':
            yield LineData(indent=len(line)-len(line.lstrip()), text=line.strip())
    yield LineData(indent=-1, text='')

def create_dict(cur_ld, line_yielder):
    next_ld = next(line_yielder)
    if cur_ld.indent >= next_ld.indent:
        return -1, next_ld    
    d = {}
    while cur_ld.indent < next_ld.indent:
        d[next_ld.text], next_ld = create_dict(next_ld, line_yielder)
    return d, next_ld

line_yielder = yield_linedata(var)
cur_ld = next(line_yielder)
result, next_line = create_dict(cur_ld, line_yielder)
print result
```